# How to initialize a heap allocated varible in the constructor

Tags: c++

This is my "code":

```
class a{
    int *var=new int;
public:
    a(int i):*var(5){};
    ~a(){}
};
```

Now of course this doesn't work. 
How can I initialize a heap variable from the constructor? (I don't want to allocate the heap variable inside the constructor )

Comment: Why do you have a parameter called `a` to the constructor? First it isn't used, second it's a bad idea to call it the same as the class. Then why don't you want to allocate the heap variable inside the constructor?

Answer (score 4):

Like so:

```
class a{
    int *var;
public:
    a(int a):var(new int(5)){};
    ~a()
    {
        delete var;
    }
}
```

The memory allocation needs to happen in the constructor. Also, you need to make sure you deallocate in the destructor.

Note your parameter `a` to the constructor isn't used. If you mean this value to initialise your class variable `a` you should change your allocation call to `new var(a)`.

Note 2: Unless you specifically need to manually manage memory (say for an exercise), a better design is to use smart pointers, such as:

```
class a{
    std::unique_ptr<int> var;
public:
    a(int a): var(std::make_unique<int>(5)){};
    ~a()
    {}
}
```

Comment: @AnatolyS - that should really have been a comment, not an edit.

Comment: @Smeeheey: ok, but if you decide to show std::unique_ptr, you should show a preffered way to construct one.

Comment: I don't disagree, otherwise I would have changed it back. But you see how much better it feels to get it out into the open ? :)